# Is this thread pool implementation OK?

Tags: c++, c++17

There are things that I am not 100% sure.
Is it possible that dangling references can be create in *add_task* method?
Is it possible that this implementation will deadlock?
I had to use *shared_ptr* in order to store *packaged_task* in the queue. Is there a better way to do it?

```
class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(int number_of_workers) {
        for (int i=0; i<number_of_workers; ++i) {
            worker_threads.push_back(std::thread{std::bind(&ThreadPool::thread_func, this)});
        }
    }
    
    ~ThreadPool() = default;
    
    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool(ThreadPool&&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ThreadPool& operator=(ThreadPool&&) = delete;
    
    template<typename Func, typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) add_task(Func&& func, Args... args) {
        using ReturnType = decltype(func(args...));
        auto ptask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<ReturnType()>>(
            std::bind(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        auto fut = ptask->get_future();
        {
            std::unique_lock lk{pool_mutex};
            task_queue.push([pt = std::move(ptask)]() { (*pt)(); });
        }
        cond.notify_one();
        return fut;
    }

    void stop() {
        {
            std::unique_lock lk{pool_mutex};
            stopped = true;
        }
        cond.notify_all();
        for (auto& th : worker_threads) {
            if (th.joinable()) {
                th.join();
            }
        }
    }

private:
    void thread_func() {
        while(true) {
            std::unique_lock lk{pool_mutex};
            if (task_queue.empty() && stopped) {
                break;
            }

            if (task_queue.empty()) {
                cond.wait(lk, [this]() { return !task_queue.empty() || stopped; });
            }

            if (!task_queue.empty()) {
                auto callable = std::move(task_queue.front());
                task_queue.pop();
                lk.unlock();
                callable();
            }
            else if (stopped) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex pool_mutex;
    std::vector<std::thread> worker_threads;
    bool stopped = false;
    std::condition_variable cond;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> task_queue;
};
```

Note, that *add_task* returns a future that can be used to wait for a specific task to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~ThreadPool() = default;
```

We need to call `stop()` in the destructor!

---

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) add_task(Func&& func, Args... args) {
    using ReturnType = decltype(func(args...));
```

For perfect forwarding we need to use `&&` for args:

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) add_task(Func&& func, Args&&... args) {
    using ReturnType = decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

---

```
ThreadPool(int number_of_workers) {
```

We need to check that this number is greater than zero. Also it might be better to use an `unsigned int` to match the result of `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`.

---

```
void thread_func() {
    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock lk{pool_mutex};
        if (task_queue.empty() && stopped) {
            break;
        }
        ...
```

I'm not sure that we should wait for the `task_queue` to be empty before stopping. I'd suggest that `stop()` should prevent threads taking any more tasks from the queue (i.e. provide a way to "cancel" tasks that haven't started executing yet).

If we wait for the queue to be empty when calling `stop()`, we're waiting for all the tasks to complete, so calling `stop()` doesn't really do much. (The calling code is already in control of whether or not it adds more tasks and waits for futures).

```
        if (task_queue.empty()) {
            cond.wait(lk, [this]() { return !task_queue.empty() || stopped; });
        }
```

We don't really need to put `cond.wait()` in an `if` statement. It will check the condition before waiting.

I'd probably go for something more like:

```
void thread_func() {
    while(true) {
        
        std::unique_lock lk{pool_mutex};
        cond.wait(lk, [this]() { return !task_queue.empty() || stopped; });
        
        if (stopped)
            break;

        assert(!task_queue.empty());
        
        auto callable = std::move(task_queue.front());
        task_queue.pop();
        
        lk.unlock();
        
        callable();
    }
}
```